# Making the shadow from a ScatterViewItem a different shape

Tags: shadow, pixelsense, scatterview

I am developing a program for Surface using Expression Blend and Visual Studio.
I have a custom user control with an ellipse and a label in a grid.
This will need to be placed in a scatterViewItem.

My problem is that the scatterviewitem will cast a rectangle shaped shadow under the ellipse shaped content. I can disable the shadow completely, but is there any way to make the shadow inherit the shape from its parent? Or can i set the shape of the scatterviewItem itself in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but shaping the shadow directly is not possible... You have to create your own ChromeShadow. Take a look at the "ScatterPuzzle" Example from the Surface SDK.